# Can we delete all partitions in disk using gparted tool as scheduled task or automatically?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, playonlinux, schedule

I want to clean up the disk before using it. I am doing this manually. Help me out to automate this/ schedule this.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) which version of Ubuntu are you using (2) under what situation would partitions on a storage device need to be regularly destroyed and recreated? 

Comment: If you're just cleaning the disk to use it, that sounds like a one-time operation.  Why would you want to automate that?.  `gparted` is a graphical utility, and may be difficult to automate - you might check some of the other tools such as `sfdisk` or `fdisk`